# jQuery textarea autogrow, do not grow until end of line/enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

There's been a lot of threads on auto-expanding textareas. Still haven't found one that I would call, "perfect". One thing that I need that I can't seem to fix, they start to grow as soon as the user starts typing. I've been trying to fix this myself with no luck. I don't want the textarea to expand until after the end of the line is reached or enter is pressed.

http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/Jrpqg/65/

Thanks!

UPDATED ANSWER:

For my situation, I not only wanted the textarea to only expand when it hit the next line/enter. But also to shrink without the text. A quick solution, in addition to the provided answer, I threw in an if the textarea is empty run the css height line as well. Will not shrink as you erase, but at least it resets the height once you erase all of the text.

```
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(this).css('height', Math.max(shadow.height() + 20, minHeight));
        }
        if(this.scrollHeight  > $this.height()) {
            $(this).css('height', Math.max(shadow.height() + 20, minHeight));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following if statement:

```
if(this.scrollHeight  > $this.height()) {
    $(this).css('height', Math.max(shadow.height() + 20, minHeight));
} else if($this.height() < shadow.height() + 20) {
    $(this).css('height', Math.max(shadow.height() + 20, minHeight));
}
```

May work or may need a little more massaging to get it to work for reducing the size as requested in comment.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the answer! This did exactly what i wanted, it did break 1 thing that worked previously though. With the statement you provided, removing text no longer shrinks the box like before: http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/Jrpqg/85/ 

I think overall, this is still better from a ux standpoint for my current layout, but if you know a way to get both working, please let me know, thanks so much!